# Regex - matching everything with number at the end

Tags: c++, regex

I have an input which is formatted like this: we have arbitrary number of whitespaces at the beginning of the string, then we have a data substring which can be anything, and it starts and ends with non-whitespace character. After the data we have again arbitrary number of whitespaces (at least one), a number and whitespaces again...

This specification is really not exact, and I'm wondering how to match it. It's obviously rather easy to match beginning and end whitespaces and number at the end. The final regex would look like that: `R("\s*(X)\s+([0-9]+)\s*)"` where `(X)` is something that matches pretty match everything. However I'm not sure what this `(X)` should look like. How to solve this problem?

One more thing - the data and the number at the end is something I want to grab if regex matches an entire line so just finding a number is not a solution.

Clarification: in the final regex I want to grab the substring and final number as two regex groups.

Comment: Doesn't that match a number too? I want the data and number to be separate "chunks" of data to be matched.

Comment: Here's an example of data for which .* don't work as expected: `Foo234bar  456`, then I want to grab "Foo234bar" and "456" and this matches "Foo234"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^\s*(\S.*?)\s+([0-9]+)\s*$
```

meaning:

- start of string `^`
- any number of whitespace chars `\s*`
- a non-whitespace `\S`
- anything, but not greedy `.*?`
- one or more whitespace chars `\s+`
- a number `[0-9]+`
- any number of whitespace chars `\s*`
- the end of the string `$`

keeping as match result the trimmed data and the number

Comment: `\S.*\S` - will this fragment match data of length one even though there are two `\S`? (e.g. will this work for `a 123`?)

Comment: @qiubit: no... i assumed that data was at least two chars; fixed... see edited version.

Comment: Now, how will this work for `Foo 234 bar 456`? If I'm understanding it correctly it will match "Foo" and "234", and I want to match "Foo 234 bar" and "456".

Comment: @qiubit: The original version was returning just one string and would match in that case. The new edited versions returns two subgroups (the data and the number) and for `Foo 234 bar 456` returns `Foo 234 bar` and `456`. It works because regexp are backtracking... to be considered valid the number must be the last thing before optional whitespace and the end of the string.